# Save DateTime in a way that you can query in Azure Mobile Services (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, azure, azure-mobile-services

I want to save a DateTime value to an Azure Mobile Services backend (javascript), but if you save it as DateTime you aren't able to query on that date. The reason I want to do that is because I want to retrieve all items that are within a certain date range. I've tried to save them as ticks, but this also doens't work because the numeric value is to large.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: By "*save them as ticks*" do you mean as a millisecond time value, like 1419465600000 for 2014-12-25 UTC?

Answer (score 0):

That's not correct - if you save a DateTime (date) value in the JS backend you can query based on that date. All relational operations (`>=, <=, <, >, ==, !=`) work find with date values.

For example, in this JS code below (for a service with a table called `so`), it can insert 4 dates, and send a range query that would return the two middle ones.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test site</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Playing with Azure</h1>
    <button onclick="insertData();">Insert data</button>
    <button onclick="readData();">read data</button>
    <ul id='results'></ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
            "https://SERVICENAME.azure-mobile.net/",
            "APPLICATIONKEY"
        );
        var table = client.getTable("so");
        function handleError(err) {
            addLog('Error: ' + err);
        }
        function addLog(text) {
            var ul = document.getElementById('results');
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
        function insertData() {
            table.insert({ myfield: 12, date: new Date(2014, 11, 1) }).then(function() {
                addLog('Inserted data in December');
                table.insert({ myfield: 11, date: new Date(2014, 10, 1) }).then(function() {
                    addLog('Inserted data in November');
                    table.insert({ myfield: 10, date: new Date(2014, 9, 1) }).then(function() {
                        addLog('Inserted data in October');
                        table.insert({ myfield: 9, date: new Date(2014, 8, 1) }).then(function() {
                            addLog('Inserted data in Setember');
                        }, handleError);
                    }, handleError);
                }, handleError);
            }, handleError);
        }

        function readData() {
            var firstDate = new Date(2014, 8, 15);
            var lastDate = new Date(2014, 10, 15);
            table.where(function(firstDate, lastDate) {
                return this.date >= firstDate && this.date <= lastDate;
            }, firstDate, lastDate).read().done(function(results) {
                addLog('Results.length: ' + results.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    addLog('Results[' + i + ']: ' + JSON.stringify(results[i]));
                }
            }, handleError);
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

A similar code can be written for a managed client as well. Haven't compiled it (written in notepad), but it would look somewhat like the code below:

```
private static MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient(
    "https://SERVICENAME.azure-mobile.net", "APPLICATION_KEY");
private static IMobileServiceTable<MyType> table = client.GetTable<MyType>();

private async void InsertData_Click(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    for (int month = 12; month >= 9; month--) {
        var date = new DateTime(2014, month, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.UTC);
        await table.InsertAsync(new MyType { date = date, myfield = month });
    }
}

private async void ReadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    var firstDate = new DateTime(2014, 9, 15, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.UTC);
    var lastDate = new DateTime(2014, 11, 15, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.UTC);
    var items = await table
        .Where(t => t.date >= firstTime && t.date <= lastTime)
        .ToListAsync();
    foreach (var item in items) {
        AddLog("Read item: " + item);
    }
}

public class MyType {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int myfield { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this `table.where(function(firstDate, lastDate) {
                return this.date >= firstDate && this.date <= lastDate;
            }, firstDate, lastDate).read()` type of thing countless times, and the promise always fails. I can make functions that reference strings and numbers, but dates always fail. < edit > i'm lying. works. You're actually my hero now.